# bash script variable from curl

Tags: bash, curl, command-substitution

I think I am missing something simple here, but here goes.

Thsi works from the command line with no problem, it give me the
required output.

```
curl -X GET \
     -H "X-Auth-Email: REDACTED" \
     -H "X-Auth-Key: REDACTED" \
     "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/aa5ac150d414359642d85f1aa434e5db/filters" | jq -r '.result[0] .id'
```

However when I try to use it in a bash script, I get no output at all

```
FWRID="$(curl -X GET \
     -H "X-Auth-Email: REDACTED" \
     -H "X-Auth-Key: REDACTED" \
     "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/aa5ac150d414359642d85f1aa434e5db/filters")" | jq -r '.result[0] .id'

echo "$FWRID"
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In your second command, you end the command substitution before the pipeline to `jq`.  That call to `jq` is what parses out the value you want, so it should be part of the command substitution:

```
FWRID=$(
    curl -X GET \
        -H 'X-Auth-Email: REDACTED' \
        -H 'X-Auth-Key: REDACTED'   \
        'https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/aaxxx/filters' |
    jq -r '.result[0] .id'
)
```

In your original command, where you leave `jq` outside of the command substitution, `jq` would read the output of the assignment to the `FWID` variable and produce some result from that.  Since the assignment doesn't produce any output, it does not do anything interesting at all.

Furthermore, since the assignment in your original command is part of a pipeline, it runs in a subshell, so the value `$FWID` is empty (or at least unchanged) in the call to `echo` later.

Comment: Many thanks. Works perfectly now.